# Delete values from a list whenever the user inputs a specific thing

Tags: python, list, input

So let's say I have a list (it's an example, but the concept is the same):

```py
List = ["I", "hate", "don't", "love", "you."]
```

How can I/Is there a way to delete multiple items from the list? I basically want the program to:

1. Take input from the user.
   How? Whenever the user types `delete x y`
   x and y represent the number given to the item in the list
2. Delete the specified items from the list whenever the person types "delete" (take it as a command. Also, it's that same delete from point #1)
   Example:

```
#The list 
List = ["I", "hate", "don't", "love", "you."]

#what the person types in the console as input
delete 2 3
```

Once the person inputs that and presses enter, the program will delete the 2nd and 3rd values from the list (in this case, from our human perspective, the words "hate" and "don't", since they take the second and third place respectively) And then it will print the list.

The problem is that I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help me? I hope I was clear enough. If not, I can try to explain it in a different way.

Comment: what if the number is greater than length of the list? and what have you tried it's just a simple program

Comment: you mean your program accepts the `"delete ..."` instruction via `input()` ?

Comment: That's a nice question, deadshot. I'll try to think of that on my own eventually. I'll try not to ask too much for help ^^; Umm I have tried something, but it's not even how I wanted it to be. I coded that if the person types "delete" (just that) it will print "What item/s from the list do you want to delete?". I set the input as an integer and asigned it to a variable(numbers) Then, I'll code "List.pop(numbers)" and then it would delete the value from the list. But then if I type 2 numbers it would give an error.

Comment: Umm yeah, Tibebes. M. The user types "delete x y" (x and y being the numbers) and it should delete the values corresponding to the numbers (like if I put 1 then it will delete the first value, and so on)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
List = ["I", "hate", "don't", "love", "you."]
command, *vals = input("Enter command: ").split()

if command=='delete':
    print([elem for i, elem in enumerate(List, start=1) if i not in list(map(int, vals))])
```

Output:

```
Enter command: delete 2 3
['I', 'love', 'you.']
```

**NOTE:** If one enters number greater than the length of list, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. My first time answering a question on here so let me know if this was ok and if you need any more help.

```
lst = ["I", "hate", "don't", "love", "you."]
```

Take input from the user. This will be saved in the form of a string.
We'll take your example of the user typing in delete 2 3

```
command = input("Enter a command")
```

This variable will be used to save the command, as per your step no.2

```
saved_command = None
```

The first if block executes if the first word of their command is 'delete'
and if saved_command is still None

```
if command.startswith("delete") and not saved_command:
    # This makes the saved_command a list. It splits the
    # command string where there are spaces so it becomes
    # ["delete", "2", "3"]. Then, we remove 'delete' so
    # it is just the numbers
    saved_command = command.split().remove("delete")
```

This second if block executes if the command given by the user starts with
delete and saved_command is not None. This will always execute if the first
if block executes since saved_command is set in that if block

```
if command.startswith("delete") and saved_command:
    # Loops through the numbers given. Note that with this, if the user
    # passes in something which is not a number, the program will crash
    for number in saved_command:
        # Removes each item from the original list.
        # Note that normally, items are indexed from 0 onwards
        # so to have it be in the way you wanted, i.e. 1 is the first
        # item, I've subtracted 1 from the number.
        # int() is used because the numbers were given as user input so
        # they would still be strings
        try:
            lst.pop(int(number) - 1)
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Note that for the saved_command value to continue to be saved, the program would have to be run inside a loop though you probably knew that.